# Determine start and end dates for multiple events and groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of three columns `site`, `Date`, and `Event`. There are two sites, a series of dates, and a factor denoting if an event occurred or not (no event is coded as 0, events are coded as 1). I need to create a table of the start and end dates for the duration of consecutive events per group.

Example Data:

```
aa <- data.frame(
  site = c('a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'),
  Date = rep(seq(as.Date('2023-11-01'),
                 as.Date('2023-11-10'),
                 by = 1),2),
  Event = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,
            1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1) 
  )
```

Output should look like this:

```
  site start_date   end_date
1    a 2023-11-03 2023-11-05
2    a 2023-11-07 2023-11-08
3    b 2023-11-01 2023-11-03
4    b 2023-11-05 2023-11-05
5    b 2023-11-08 2023-11-10
```

I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)

aa %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(
    start_date = ifelse(Event != 0 & lag(Event == 0, n = 1), Date, NA),
    end_date = ifelse(Event != 0 & lead(Event == 0, n = 1), Date, NA)
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(start_date) | !is.na(end_date)) %>%
  fill(c(start_date, end_date), .direction = "downup") %>%
  distinct(site, start_date, end_date)
```

My attempt does not work for a few reasons. First, the dates are returned as numbers rather than dates. Second, my approach has issues when the event either starts on the first date or ends on the last date. Lastly, it is not picking up the correct number of events per group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost always easier to create a new column to define your distinct event periods, then group the data you want using the new column values:

```
library(dplyr)

aa %>%
  mutate(eve_grp = cumsum(Event != lag(Event, default = 0))) %>% # Define unique "Event" periods in new column
  filter(Event == 1) %>% # Filter out unneeded rows
  group_by(site, eve_grp) %>% # Group sites by new column you created
  mutate(start_date = min(Date), # Get min/max dates for each separate group
         end_date = max(Date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(site, start_date, end_date) %>%
  distinct() # Get unique rows

aa
# A tibble: 5 × 3
 site   start_date end_date  
<chr>    <date>     <date>    
1 a     2023-11-03 2023-11-05
2 a     2023-11-07 2023-11-08
3 b     2023-11-01 2023-11-03
4 b     2023-11-05 2023-11-05
5 b     2023-11-08 2023-11-10
```